# Subject.getSubject() always return null after jdk1.6.0_39

Tags: java, security, jmx

We use following code to get subject in JMX Server. The `Subject.getSubject(acc)` always return `null` event the user is authenticated. It is Ok for JDK older than 1.6.0_39.
So, is there any body knows if it is a JDK's bug, or there are something changed in JDK after 1.6.0_39?
If the feature changed after 1.6.0_39, how i get current user's subject?

```
AccessControlContext acc = AccessController.getContext();
Subject subject = Subject.getSubject(acc);
```

Comment: Is `acc` null by any chance ?

Comment: I already checked the acc passed to Subject.getSubject(acc) is not null.